# Triangle tiling proof

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

How to prove that the number of triangles in the tiling below can be found by the formula

$$\left\lfloor\frac{n(n+2)(2n+1)}8\right\rfloor\;,$$

where $n$ is the number of vertical layers? (For the following triangle, the answer is

$$\left\lfloor\frac{5\cdot7\cdot11}8\right\rfloor=48\;.$$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203873/how-many-triangles) derives an exact solution that does not use the floor function; instead it gives slightly different expressions for the cases of even $n$ and odd $n$. You need only check that both of these expressions reduce to your formula with the floor function. The answer by MvG gives some useful references.

Comment: thanks, was searching for a solution and haven't found it here

Comment: @Kudayar: You’re welcome. (Things aren’t always easy to find here; I had to use Google to find it.)