# What is the explicit formula for the sequence representing the number of any triangles in a triangular grid?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the explicit formula for the sequence representing the number of any triangles in a triangular grid, like those below?

[image]

#### Context

- Counting only up-facing triangles of size one, we get *triangular numbers*.
- Counting both up-facing and down-facing triangles of size one, we get *square numbers* (that is, perfect squares)

But what is the total number of all triangles of any size? Here are some values for small $n$.

[image]

Comment: I'd also like to know what you mean - do you mean those triangles pointing up (1,3,6,...)? Do you mean all of the smallest triangles (1,4,9,...)? Do you mean all the triangles of all sizes (1,5,13,...)?

Comment: @Mike: The latter. See my update.

Comment: The accepted answer to the MSE post, [how many triangles](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203873/how-many-triangles), by Brian M. Scott seems useful. He generalizes the particular question in that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values fit $a_n=2n^2-2n+1$ To find that, two levels of differences gives a constant $4$, so the leading term is $(4/2!)n^2$. Subtract that off and you can find the rest.