# The number Triangles in this picture

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

I want  a method  for find the number triangles in the under image.

[image]

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203873/how-many-triangles

This has already been answered.

Comment: I want world peace and equitable distribution of wealth.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the top. Take every juncture point and calculate the number of triangles starting, and going downward (i.e. the triangle is wholly under that point), from that point. Then add up.