# How to find the number of triangles of any size for figure n

Tags: sequences-and-series, triangles

Find an explicit formula for the number of triangles of any size in figure n. Include upward facing and downward facing triangles.

I tried counting the number of triangles in each figure (1,5, and 13) and looking for a pattern. I tried to put it in the form of a sequence, but I got lost very quickly.

All help is appreciated!

[image: Triangle Diagram]

Comment: More than you'll ever want to know about these numbers at https://oeis.org/A002717

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203873/how-many-triangles asks about a particular $n$, not the general $n$, but the answers there tackle the general problem.