# Cases when rounding makes approximations exact

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, rounding-error

This is a bit of a soft question, but I hope it's still precise enough. I'm interested in finding cases where a complicated expression has a simple approximation which becomes exact again upon rounding / flooring / ceiling. Examples follow.

An exact expression for the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) is
$$
D_n = n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.
$$
The sum here is very close to $e^{-1}$, and in fact the following formula also holds:
$$
D_n=\left[\frac{n!}{e}\right]
$$
where the brackets denote rounding to the nearest integer.

There are even nicer examples which involve only rational numbers and unify different cases of a problem. For example, the [number of triangles in a triangular matchstick arrangement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203873/how-many-triangles?noredirect=1&lq=1) can be expressed either by the case-by-case formula
$$
\binom{n+2}3+\begin{cases}
\frac1{24}n(n+2)(2n-1),&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\\\
\frac1{24}\left(n^2-1\right)(2n+3),&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
or by the floored expression
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{n(n+2)(2n+1)}8\right\rfloor.
$$
A second example of this kind would be counting the number of triangles inscribed in an $n$-gon up to rotations and reflections which (if I'm not mistaken) comes out to
$$
\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{12} + \begin{cases}
\frac{n-2}{4},&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\\\
\frac{n-1}{4},&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}+\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3},&\text{if }n\text{ is divisible by }3\\\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and which is also equal to
$$
\left[\frac{n^2}{12}\right].
$$
What are some other instances of this phenomenon?